# NodeJS and AWS Firehose consistently cause OOM errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I can consistently produce OOM errors when using AWS-SDK Firehose (v3) and NodeJS (16.19.1).

This is an application that sends many `PutRecordCommand` directly to AWS Firehose. We are well within our limits (i.e. we aren't being throttled).

See the memory dump below and the code in question.

Question: is this a known issue with AWS-SDK Firehose v3? Or am I fundamentally doing something wrong?

```js
const DeliveryStreamName = 'REDACTED'

const command = new PutRecordCommand({
  DeliveryStreamName,
  Record: { Data: Buffer.from(REDACTED) },
})

const client = new FirehoseClient({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  endpoint: REDACTED
  credentials: REDACTED
})

await client.send(command)
```

OOM error with `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192` option set.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[252:0x5d16cf0]   189663 ms: Mark-sweep 8111.2 (8235.3) -> 8102.4 (8238.3) MB, 325.8 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.404, current mu = 0.054) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[252:0x5d16cf0]   190004 ms: Mark-sweep 8114.2 (8239.7) -> 8105.8 (8241.9) MB, 324.4 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.260, current mu = 0.050) allocation failure GC in old space requested
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb08e80 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1b70e  [node]
 3: 0xce1890 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xce1c37 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xe992a5  [node]
 6: 0xea8f6d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: 0xeabc6e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0xe6cee2 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 9: 0xe654f4 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xe67200 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
11: 0x10f85e8 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0xced189 v8::String::Utf8Length(v8::Isolate*) const [node]
13: 0xade517  [node]
14: 0xd3ddfe  [node]
15: 0xd3f21f v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
16: 0x15d9cf9  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```